# Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, matplotlib

Имеются два класса. Класс **MainW** отвечает за графический интерфейс пользователя, класс **LoadData** отвечает за обработку данных, полученных от пользователя.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from MainWindow import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class LoadData(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoadData, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def hist(self, y):
        x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
        my_xticks = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
        plt.hist(y, x)
        plt.show()
    def run(self):
        y = np.array([1,1,1,2,2])
        self.hist(y)

class MainW(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)   
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select)
    def select(self):
        self.task = LoadData(self)
        self.task.start()

if __name__=="__main__": 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainW()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я запускаю скрипт через консоль. Когда я нажимаю кнопку `select`: в отдельном потоке открывается окно `matplotlib`'a **plt.show()** с гистограммой.

1. Я закрываю окно с гистограммой, закрываю приложение, появляется следующая ошибка:

> Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread

и приложение крашится.

2. Я закрываю приложение (без закрытия окна с гистограммой). Консоль просто зависает (не могу ничего писать) до тех пор пока её не закрою.

Какие существуют варианты решения данной проблемы?

Comment: не нужно запускать гуишные окна в отдельных потоках

Comment: `matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')` помогает?

Comment: См. [embedding in qt5](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt5.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте этот пример:

```
import sys
import random

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

import numpy as np

from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow                     

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import Qt

class LoadData(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignalLoadData = Qt.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)  #(class)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    

    def run(self):
        #myArray = [2,1,1,3,2]      
        # Создайте список из 6 случайных чисел от 0 до 3 (оба включительно)
        myArray = [random.randint(0, 3) for i in range(6)]
        y = np.array(myArray)
        self.threadSignalLoadData.emit(y)

class MainW(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)   
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Select)
        self.setGeometry(1020, 100, 350, 270)

    def Select(self):
        self.task = LoadData()   
        self.task.threadSignalLoadData.connect(self.on_threadSignalLoadData)
        self.task.start()

    def on_threadSignalLoadData(self, y):
        x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
        my_xticks = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
        plt.cla()
        plt.hist(y, x)
        plt.draw()
        plt.show()       

if __name__=="__main__": 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainW()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, это действительно, наверное, единственный способ решения данной проблемы.